# Difference B/w LTxxx Ics and Lmvxx Ics

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, electrical

I have been strolling towards being a circuit designer, using eagle and ltspice and i am trying to learn about new ic's and stuff. recently the thought about how does an LTXXX module and LVXXX(or LMXX) module differ to each other if they are both based on op-amps.

Comment: I'm just curious; when you say circuit designer, are you talking about PCB designer, or IC designer?

Comment: Each company had its own part number structure while many companies have merged. LT is Linear Tech who also make LM devices common to many and LTC is CMOS vs Bipolar. And in logic there are 40 different common variations but each consistent for voltage range or drive impedance or speed tradeoffs just like TTL was 74xxx,74S, 74LS,74L next CMOS 74HC,... ...74HCT, etc

Comment: thanks tony and daniel. also i am just a rookie in the field of circuit designing. i have just completed circuits based on 555 timer, lmvxxx modules and some motor ic and sound amps. i want to be an ic designer and if could would love any sort of help you guys can provide in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a few numbers that indicated a similar IC, but otherwise they are completely independent numbers and have no relationship to each other. Early on 30+ years ago there may have been some number sharing, but if that did occur it was usually in the form of everyone having the same number (like the OP27) and sometimes a different suffix. If you want to learn about the numbers the best way to do this is through the manufacturers websites. The numbers also have very little to do with what it is, and LT1763 is an LDO an LT1867 is an OP Amp

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i am actually concerned as, in ltspice(schematic software) there's a huge collection of LTXXX module, so i was wondering if i can use them as lmvxxx modules..

Comment: Same rules apply, a part number is a part number, they are not similar in spice either